# success message is not working with create view

Tags: django

I have used `SuccessMessageMixin` class but then also in the createview I did'nt get the success message but in the `updateview` it is working when I return the `super().form_valid(form)`

```
class DepartmentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin ,CreateView):

template_name = 'departments/create_department.html'
form_class = DepartmentForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('departments:departments')
permission_required = ('departments.add_department',)

    def form_valid(self, form):

       department = form.save(commit=False)
       department.created_by = self.request.user
       department.updated_by = self.request.user
       department.slug = slugify(uuid.uuid4())
       department.save()

       message = '[{"created": {}}]'

       # retriving ContentType object
       ct_obj = ContentType.objects.get(model='department')

       # creating history object
       history = History.objects.create(
           action_time=timezone.now(),
           action='created',
           user=department.created_by,
           content_type=ct_obj,
           object_id=department.id,
           change_message=message,
       )
       history.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't actually set a success message.

```
class DepartmentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin ,CreateView):
    success_message = "Department was created successfully"
    ...
```

Note, your `form_valid` is saving things twice. You should do:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.slug = slugify(uuid.uuid4())
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: how prevent this twice saving please help